# Cannot link library using CMake in Android Studio: Unable to load native library

Tags: android, c++, cmake

As soon as I want to add my own library via `target_link_libraries(...)` my application crashes with the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.process, PID: 3651
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.process/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/app/my.process/lib/x86/libnative-activity.so
```

My CMake file in `src/cpp/main/CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# build native_app_glue as a static lib
add_library(app-glue STATIC
            ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

# Native-Activity
add_library(native-activity SHARED "")

# Native-Library
add_library(native-lib SHARED "")

include("Native/CMakeLists.txt")

# Link the native-activity
target_sources(native-activity PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp")

target_include_directories(native-activity PRIVATE
                           ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(native-activity
                      android
                      app-glue
                      log)

target_link_libraries(native-activity native-lib)
```

and the CMake file in `src/cpp/main/Native/CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
set_target_properties(native-lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

If I remove the following line from the first CMake file in `src/cpp/main/CMakeLists.txt` compilation works:

```
target_link_libraries(native-activity native-lib)
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I found out that using `target_link_libraries(native-lib native-activity)` works but that is contradicting with my understanding of how linking works.

Comment: I reread on linking and how the `target_link_libraries(...)` function works and I was right, it is not the way it is intended to do. However, I found a simple solution to my problem by providing absolute paths to the library as following: 1) `find_library(native-lib my-native-lib)` 2) `target_link_libraries(native-activity ${my-native-lib})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was using the [find_library(...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html) CMake command and use the full path to link the library *native-lib* against *native-activity*.

The working CMake file is shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# build native_app_glue as a static lib
add_library(app-glue STATIC
            ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue/android_native_app_glue.c)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

# Native-Activity
add_library(native-activity SHARED "")

# Native-Library
add_library(native-lib SHARED "")

include("Native/CMakeLists.txt")

# Link the native-activity
target_sources(native-activity PRIVATE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/main.cpp")

target_include_directories(native-activity PRIVATE
                           ${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/android/native_app_glue)

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(native-activity
                      android
                      app-glue
                      log)

find_library(native-lib my-native-lib)

target_link_libraries(native-activity ${my-native-lib})
```